# awk: convert one column file in a multiple columns csv file using

Tags: csv, ubuntu, awk

I have a file that look like that

```
a
b
c
g
v
b
g
h
t
y
```

I am looking for an awk solution to convert the above file in something like this

```
a,b,c,g
v,b,g,h
t,y
```

If I consult [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88142/command-to-transpose-swap-rows-and-columns-of-a-text-file) I guess I could use awk to first transpose and then divide my unique line in multiple lines. However, I think I cannot really understand how.
Any good tutorials/link/cookbook/suggestion to consult to do this?

Comment: This has been answered many times before http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/text-processing-join-lines-with-commas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR%4 {printf $0",";next} 1; END {print ""}' file
```

When the line number is not dividable by four, just print the line without the newline and add a comma. Otherwise, print the line with the newline.

You can print a newline at the end by using the `END` block.

Comment: you may need an extra `END {print ""}` to have a new line in the end. Also, this gives a trailing comma is number of lines !% 4. +1 however for the idea and explanation.

Comment: Alternatively `awk '{printf $0(NR%4?",":RS)}END{print ""}'`

Comment: The solutions proposed (Tim's and Jidder's) add to the output either an unwanted comma or an unwanted newline.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a possible solution

```
% cat p
echo 'a
b
c
g
v
b
g
h
t
y' | awk '{x=x==""?$0:x "," $0} NR%4==0{print x;x=""} END {if(x!="") print x}'
% sh p
a,b,c,g
v,b,g,h
t,y
%
```

A line of output is built joining with a comma a number of input lines, when the number of elements is equal to 4 we print and reset the output line.

At the `END` we have to print the final line, if it was not just printed before.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed '$!N;$!N;$!N;s/\n/,/g' file
```

The way this works is that `$! N` executes `N` if the end of the file is not yet reached, and `N` fetches the next line and appends it to the pattern space. This is done three times so that four (or less, at the end of the file) lines are in the pattern space, and then `s/\n/,/g` replaces the newlines between them with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet:

`paste -d, - - - - | sed 's/,*$//'`

Pipe your file into that.