# Loop for n lines - create csv

Tags: bash

I've a text file that look likes this :

```
data1-1
data1-2
data1-3
data2-1
data2-2
data2-3
data3-1
data3-2
data3-3
```

And I want to transform it to a csv that look like :

```
data1-1,data1-2,data1-3
data2-1,data2-2,data2-3
data3-1,data3-2,data3-3
```

What is the best way to solve this problem? I can create my csv with with a echo command

> echo "object1,object2,object3" > test.csv

But after that, I'm not sure about what is the best loop method. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: you want each line to have 3 fields or all fields with same prefix ("datax")?

Comment: See: [awk: convert one column file in a multiple columns csv file using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27861417/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
paste -d "," - - - <file >test.csv
```

Output to test.csv:

```
data1-1,data1-2,data1-3
data2-1,data2-2,data2-3
data3-1,data3-2,data3-3
```